# Embedded Page for linkedin job posts

Tags: html, web, timeline

I was wondering if anyone knows whether a job posting timeline/stream can be embedded into the HTML of a web page (on a website) like you can do with facebook Posts and Comments?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs you might be interested in:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/jymbii

You might be able to tweak this to do what you want, i have never looked into it tbh.

All LinkedIn developer plugins:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins

Comment: Thanks for this, it was very helpful.